# Как заставить Docker сохранять все данные в указанной папке?

Tags: windows, docker

Я установил Docker и хочу, чтобы все образы и данные контейнеров хранились в папке D:\Docker. В [документации на сайте Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon) я прочитал, что для этого нужно прописать в файл deamon.json следующее:

```
"data-root": "d:\\Docker"
```

Я сделал это и перезапустил Docker. Он пытался перезапуститься несколько минут, после чего выдал такую ошибку:

```
Failed to restart

System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException:
Cancellation token triggered before we finished reading from the stream.
   в HttpOverStream.ByLineReader.<ReadLineAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в HttpOverStream.Client.DialMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в Docker.Core.Logging.LoggingMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext() в C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\Logging\LoggingMessageHandler.cs:строка 30
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в Docker.Core.HttpClientExtensions.<GetJsonAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext() в C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\HttpClientExtensions.cs:строка 16
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в Docker.ApiServices.LifecycleClient.<DockerStartAsync>d__10.MoveNext() в C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\LifecycleClient.cs:строка 122
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в Docker.LinuxkitDaemonStartup.<StartAsync>d__5.MoveNext() в C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\LinuxkitDaemonStartup.cs:строка 30
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.<DoStartAsync>d__25.MoveNext() в C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:строка 160
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.<WrapAsyncInCancellationException>d__0.MoveNext() в C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:строка 20
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() в C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:строка 29
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   в Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() в C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:строка 38
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.EngineStateMachine.<StartAsync>d__14.MoveNext() в C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\EngineStateMachine.cs:строка 69
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в Docker.Engines.Engines.<RestartAsync>d__26.MoveNext() в C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\Engines.cs:строка 266
```

Что я делаю не так? Что следует исправить, чтобы достичь нужного мне эффекта?

Comment: А hellowworld нормально отрабатывает?

Comment: @donRumata, да, вполне.

Comment: Возможно проблема в больших и маленьких буквах. Пути в линуксе - регистрозависимы, т.е. `./MyDir/` и `./mydir` - это 2 разных пути. Возможно из-за трансляции возникает коллизия.